# How to fetch multiple rows in mnesia

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

```
{atomic,[R]}={atomic,[{ios,2,"hhh"},{ios,1,"hhh"}]}
```

this produces an error.What am trying to do is basicaaly fetch multiple rows from mnesia table and use case statement to handle any error(if there does not exist a record for which i am searching).Whenever there is one or zero tuple corresponding to the item searched it works fine but whenn there is more than one tuple it throws the error.Below is full code

```
x( Artist) ->
Query = fun() ->
        mnesia:match_object({ios,'_', Artist } )
    end,
 X=case mnesia:transaction( Query) of
    {atomic,[R]} ->
io:format("Text found in Android : ~p~n", [R#ios.txt]) ;
    {atomic,[]} ->
        Id=1000, 
        io:format("No records with ID = ~p~n", [Id]);
   {aborted,{no_exists,ios}}->
          hi        
end,
X.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request find multiple row, the answer is (I guess) `{atomic,List}` where List is a list that contains more than one element and thus cannot match with `[R]` which is a list of one single element.

What you can do is receive the list and traverse it to print the results;

```
x( Artist) ->
Query = fun() ->
        mnesia:match_object({ios,'_', Artist } )
    end,
 case mnesia:transaction( Query) of
    {atomic,[]} ->
        Id=1000, 
        io:format("No records with ID = ~p~n", [Id]);
    {atomic,L} ->
        [io:format("Text found in Android : ~p~n", [R#ios.txt]) || R <- L] ;
    {aborted,{no_exists,ios}}->
          hi        
end.
```

Comment: :thank u very much.It worked for me.One more question is Do I need to add more error cases(at currenyt time there are 3({atomic,[]},{atomic,L},{aborted,{no_exists,ios}})).if yes what those could be?

Comment: If you want to be more generic, you can match on {aborted,_Reason} and you will catch all possible error cases (from the transaction point of view) see documentation at [www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#match_object-1]